# Error in installing Turi Create on Windows

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, llvmlite, turi

I am using Windows 10 and run Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda. At first I wanted to install Turi Create on Anaconda but failed to do so. Then I started installing Turi Create through WSL using Ubuntu. But after running the command **$pip install turicreate** I am getting the following error:
**ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite**

My python version is 3.6.9

The full error traceback is given below

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
>   /home/rishad/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
>   sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-VYksx0
>          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/   Complete output (15 lines):   running bdist_wheel   /home/rishad/venv/bin/python
>   /tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py   LLVM version... 6.0.0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 168, in 
>         main()
>       File "/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 158, in main
>         main_posix('linux', '.so')
>       File "/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 120, in main_posix
>         raise RuntimeError(msg)   RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.0.x, got u'6.0.0'. Be sure to set
>   LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.   Read the documentation at
>   http://llvmlite.pydata.org/ for more information about building
>   llvmlite.
>
> error: command '/home/rishad/venv/bin/python' failed with exit
>   status 1   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed
>   building wheel for llvmlite

And then the next error

> Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: /home/rishad/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record /tmp/pip-record-Tv5u1Z/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/rishad/venv/include/site/python2.7/llvmlite
>            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/
>       Complete output (18 lines):
>       running install
>       running build
>       got version from file /tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version':
>   '0.32.0', 'full': '26059d238f4ba23dff74703dd27168591d889edd'}
>       running build_ext
>       /home/rishad/venv/bin/python /tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
>       LLVM version... 6.0.0
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 168, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 158, in main
>     main_posix('linux', '.so')
>   File "/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 120, in main_posix
>     raise RuntimeError(msg)
> RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.0.x, got u'6.0.0'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.
> Read the documentation at http://llvmlite.pydata.org/ for more information about building llvmlite.
>
> error: command '/home/rishad/venv/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/rishad/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import
> ```
>
> sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D6ZY7E/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record /tmp/pip-record-Tv5u1Z/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/rishad/venv/include/site/python2.7/llvmlite Check the logs for
>   full command output.

Comment: That's one of the the last lines of the error message. Please post _the full traceback_.

Comment: The whole traceback is quite large. I got 2 errors.

Comment: I quote the error message: "Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.x, got `u'6.0.0'`". So you're using an unsupported version of LLVM.